# ¿Cómo puedo devolver un string con números intercalados entre letras?

Tags: javascript, array, string, javascript-metodo

Tengo una tarea en la cual la entrada es por ejemplo "Sam" y la salida deberá ser S0a1m2, para esto tenemos que usar un ciclo for adentro de una función.

Se me ocurre que puedo aplicarle un split por caracteres a ese String, para que quede [`S`,`a`,`m`] y después un join(" ") para dejar:  "S a m" y con el for acceder a esos espacios en blancos, pero no sé con que método pudiera agregarle los números, que imagino que serán sus índices.

Comment: Hola Samuel, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

Comment: jajaj  suele pasar, comentarios borrados..

Comment: Con esos espacios en blanco te queda `S0A1M`, no `S0A1M2`

Comment: Eso lo pensé cuando preguntaba, por eso quise poner como yo lo estaría resolviendo así esté equivocado, pero muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Soy nuevo por aquí y por eso no estoy tan enterado aún jaja, iré viendo como mejorar las preguntas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mi se me ocurre esto.

```js
const string = "Sam"

const result = string.split('').reduce(( nuevo,letra,index )=> nuevo+letra+index,"")
console.log(result)
```

El split convierte el string a un arreglo donde cada espacio del array es una letra, y luego a ese array se le hace un .reduce para volver a juntarlo, solo que con el numero de index que nos proporciona el parametro index de la función que le especificamos.

[Click aqui para saber mas del Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo, ni sabía de ese método porqué aún no llegamos hasta allá, pero me parece muy útil, iré a investigarlo ya jaja

Comment: @SamuelBenedetti De nada, los strings y los arreglos en javascript vienen con métodos muy útiles que puedes indagar en la documentación de javascript.

Si te sirvió puedes marcarlo como respuesta aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Si vale el lado sencillo, dejo este código:

```js
let palabra = "Sam";
let salida = "";

for( let i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++ ) {
    salida += palabra[ i ] + i;
}

console.log( salida );
```

En cada iteración, tomamos una letra de la palabra y la concatenamos con el contador (**i**), al mismo tiempo que le agregamos a la variable de salida, el resultado de esta operación.

Comment: Está perfecto, justo lo que andamos viendo, sólo tengo un conflicto, porqué me está costando un poco entender porqué se imprime junto, y no Sam 012, creería porqué es lo que vamos ejecutando en cada iteración.                                          O sea, a la variable salida primero se le suma la letra en la posición i y después el índice y así, y a pesar de tenerlo claro, me cuesta terminar de asimilarlo, pero bueno, tendré la constancia hasta que se me quede jaja

Comment: Es fácil, en la primer iteración, **salida** toma el valor de **palabra[ 0 ]** que es "`S`" concatenada con **i** que es "`0`", osea que pasa a tener la cadena "`S0`", en la segunda, el contenido de **salida** se concatenará a su vez, con la concatenación de **palabra[ 1 ]** que es "`a`" con **i** que es "`1`", osea, pasará a tener "`Soa1`" etc.